# Request for "Review suggested edits" page to render edited formulas

Tags: feature-request, editing, math-display, review, suggested-edits

On the "review suggested edits" page, even when you choose the "rendered output" view, it will still show the raw TeX of the formula you edited.  (Unedited formulas in the answer are rendered, though.) With a large formula, this makes it harder for the reviewer to tell if the edit is correct.

(See this edit I made, for an example of this behavior: https://stats.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/153225)

This is apparently because the MathJax rendering doesn't allow for the red/green highlights, as noted in the accepted answer for this question: [MathJax half-broken in suggested edit diffs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232123/mathjax-half-broken-in-suggested-edit-diffs)

Since there doesn't seem to be a way to highlight within the rendered output, I would like to request a feature where the output is rendered, and the entire rendered equation is marked as a change.  (If the user wants to see which part changed, they could still do so on the source diff view, which would stay the same as what they have today on both views.)  [This suggestion echos Ilmari Karonen's answer to the bug linked above.]

Comment: See also this post: [single-character edits in formulas](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1977/single-character-edits-in-formulas), making a essentially the same point to your (2)

Comment: Given that (2) is a duplicate, perhaps remove it from here altogether? In order to focus this on issue #1 which is arguably a bug.

Comment: @amoeba Good idea.  I've edited accordingly.

Comment: This is not a bug. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232123. You can change it to be feature-request though.

Comment: @amoeba Ah, that makes sense.  I've tried to re-word this as a feature request, as you suggest.